# How can I set size of a button?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, button, size

I put my buttons in a JPane with GridLayout. Then I put JPanel into another JPanel with BoxLayout.Y_AXIS. I want buttons in the GridLayout to be square. I use tmp.setSize(30,30) and it does not work. I also try to use `new GridLayout(X, Y, 4, 4)` but I cannot figure out what X and Y are. So, what is the correct way to do this stuff?

**ADDED:**

I still cannot solve the problem. Here is the code of what I am trying to do:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PanelModel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colored Trails");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        firstPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        JButton btn;
        for (int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<=4; j++) {
                btn = new JButton();
                btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                firstPanel.add(btn);
            }
        }

        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
        secondPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 13));
        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<=13; j++) {
                btn = new JButton();
                btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
                secondPanel.add(btn);
            }
        }

        mainPanel.add(firstPanel);
        mainPanel.add(secondPanel);
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setSize(400,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is that Java tries to make width of the `firstPanel` and `secondPanel` equal! Moreover, Java tries to to fill all height of the window. How can I remove this behavior?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The following bit of code does what you ask for. Just make sure that you assign enough space so that the text on the button becomes visible

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4,4,4));

for(int i=0 ; i<16 ; i++){
    JButton btn = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
    btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    panel.add(btn);
}
frame.setContentPane(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The X and Y (two first parameters of the GridLayout constructor) specify the number of rows and columns in the grid (respectively). You may leave one of them as 0 if you want that value to be unbounded.

**Edit**

I've modified the provided code and I believe it now conforms to what is desired:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colored Trails");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
firstPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
firstPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
JButton btn;
for (int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j<=4; j++) {
        btn = new JButton();
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        firstPanel.add(btn);
    }
}

JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
secondPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 13));
secondPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(520, 200));
for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j<=13; j++) {
        btn = new JButton();
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        secondPanel.add(btn);
    }
}

mainPanel.add(firstPanel);
mainPanel.add(secondPanel);
frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);

frame.setSize(520,600);
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(520,600));
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Basically I now set the preferred size of the panels and a minimum size for the frame.

Comment: I tried this code. It works. But if I try to implement the same idea in my program, it does not work. I think that the reason is that I include my JPanel (with the GridLayout) to another JPanel (with BoxLayout.Y_AXIS).

Comment: @Roman If you want more specific help you'll need to post some sample code!

Comment: Why not share one `new Dimension(40, 40)` between all buttons instead of instantiating 16 of them?

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 5):

Try with `setPreferredSize` instead of `setSize`.

**UPDATE:** `GridLayout` take up all space in its container, and `BoxLayout` seams to take up all the width in its container, so I added some glue-panels that are invisible and just take up space when the user stretches the window. I have just done this horizontally, and not vertically, but you could implement that in the same way if you want it.

Since `GridLayout` make all cells in the same size, it doesn't matter if they have a specified size. You have to specify a size for its container instead, as I have done.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PanelModel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colored Trails");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        firstPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(4*100, 4*100));
        for (int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<=4; j++) {
                firstPanel.add(new JButton());
            }
        }

        JPanel firstGluePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        firstGluePanel.add(firstPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        firstGluePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        firstGluePanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(13, 5));
        secondPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5*40, 13*40));
        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<=13; j++) {
                secondPanel.add(new JButton());
            }
        }

        JPanel secondGluePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        secondGluePanel.add(secondPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        secondGluePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        secondGluePanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainPanel.add(firstGluePanel);
        mainPanel.add(secondGluePanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);

        //frame.setSize(400,600);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiler writes that it cannot find method called `setPreferredSize`.

Answer (score 4):

GridLayout is often not the best choice for buttons, although it might be for your application. A good reference is the [tutorial on using Layout Managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). If you look at the GridLayout example, you'll see the buttons look a little silly -- way too big.

A better idea might be to use a FlowLayout for your buttons, or if you know exactly what you want, perhaps a GroupLayout. (Sun/Oracle [recommend](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) that GroupLayout or GridBag layout are better than GridLayout when hand-coding.)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it.

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JFrame frame = new JFrame("SAP Multiple Entries");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,10,10,10));
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                
frame.setSize(512, 512);
JButton button = new JButton("Select File");
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(256, 256));
panel.add(button);
    
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    
            keep = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        
                            
            // System.out.println(keep);
            //out.println(file.flag); 

            if (file.flag==true) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is done! \nLocation: " + file.path , "Success Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "failure", "not okay", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
});

frame.add(button);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```